# Error and warning while installing CodeIgniter through Composer

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, composer-php, codeigniter-3

I tried to install CodeIgniter through composer using this:

```
composer require bcit-ci/CodeIgniter
```

And it installed successfully I got a warning, see screenshot

[image]

And then I tried to install with this:

```
composer require codeigniter/framework
```

and I got a fatal error, see screenshot here

[image]

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

See all screenshots here: [http://imgur.com/a/zsnER](https://imgur.com/a/zsnER)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is weird that composer trying to install the very first package 1.0.0 , works perfectly at my side.

however , you will need to pass the package version statically as follows:

```
composer require codeigniter/framework:"3.1-stable"
```

this will often -till the answer date- install 3.1.0 version,

you may try to download the latest version :

```
composer require codeigniter/framework:"3.1.4"
```

Comment: 3.1-stable will not install 3.1.0

Comment: @Narf , weird , when I've tried to install 3.1-stable i got `- Installing codeigniter/framework (3.1.0)`

Comment: Hmm ... I am wrong about that then. What's weird is that Composer apparently assumes that `-stable` is an alias for `.0` - this is both incorrect and in this case confusing, as `3.1-stable` is the name of a branch in the CI repo.

Comment: @Narf so i think that the problem is related with his composer someway , when he tries to `composer require codeigniter/framework` the composer points to the version 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the cache of Composer and tried to install again and I got success.